# Как написать чат на asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xml

Грубо говоря, я только начал изучать ASP.NET. До этого я изучал C# по Шилдту. Читаю я книгу по ASP.NET Мэтью Макдональда. Прочитал я пока только 6 глав этой книги. Как все известно, лучший способ что то освоить, это написать небольшей проект. Я хочу попробовать написать свой чат. Я поискал в интернете, как должен выглядить чат. [Как написать чат](http://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-97931-kak-napisat-chat). Для себя определился, как именно он будет выглядить, согласно указанных способов по данной статье. Пока без AJAX. Но у меня ступор, с чего начать. Прошу меня натолкнуть в этом направление. Конкретно, я не знаю что писать в коде, какие классы использовать и т.д.

Для чата я буду использовать фреймы. Одно окно сообщения, другое с текстбоксом и кнопкой для отправки сообщений. Все сообщения я буду хранить в XML. Чат я реализую с авторизацией пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот и начните с **авторизации**, потом добавьте **регистрацию**. После этого сделайте **скелет страницы**, которая бы, в теории, могла отправлять/получать сообщения. То, что он будет выглядеть ужасно - не важно. Напишите **серверную часть** и проверьте работает ли ваша страница на практике. Если нет - исправляйте. Затем делайте ajax, красивый дизайн и прочией радости.

А вообще, просто **начните**. Если этот чат вам сделать не срочно, то **переписывайте** каждый раз, когда поймете, что узнали что-то новое. Со временем переписывать перестанете и всё станет немного **понятнее**.

**Ссылки** же есть и посолиднее, чем та, которую вы привели:

- [Реализация web-чата на](http://kavayii.blogspot.com/2010/08/web-aspnet.html) [Asp.Net](http://Asp.Net)
- [Делаем чат на](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145077/) [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) с помощью Web Socket
- [Чат на ASP: от простого к сложному](http://wmate.ru/publics/article130.html)

**p.s.:** *не в том вы направлении двигаетесь - в самом начале стоило бы очень-очень постараться, а вопрос задавать после того как наткнетесь на проблему, решения которой найти ну никак не получается.*